# Updating What Function is returning Which is Inside Render Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have one function inside render method called  loadSpot2() which is returning html elements.

```
    loadSpot2 = () =>{
        if(this.props.townData.length ==0 || this.constructionTimer == true){
          return;
        }
        if(this.props.townData[0].spots[1].construction==true){
          console.log("lets start construction!");
          this.constructionTimer = true;
          this.state.constructionTime = this.props.townData[0].spots[1].endTime- this.props.townData[0].spots[1].startTime;


         this.constructionCountDownInterval= setInterval(this.constructionCountDown(),1000)
//i would like to render this return statement.
          return (

            <div className ="newBuilding">
            <img className="factorySize" src="http://i.hizliresim.com/NDE1rN.png"></img>

            <label className="newBuildingName">{this.state.constructionTime}</label>
            </div>
              )
        }
        if(this.props.townData[0].spots[1].buildingName =="factory" && this.constructionTimer ==false){
          return (
        <img className="factorySize" src="http://i.hizliresim.com/JDA8WB.png"></img>

          )

        }else if(this.constructionTimer==false && this.props.townData[0].spots[1].constructingBuildingName ==""){
          //initially function comes here rendering below:
          return (
            <img  onClick={() =>this.openNewBuildingModel(2)} className="buildSign" src="http://i.hizliresim.com/zM51J6.png"></img>

              ) 
        }


              }
```

Initially `this.constructionTimer==false` and `this.props.townData[0].spots[1].constructingBuildingName ==""` so i am rendering last else statement so far so good.The problem is if i make `this.props.townData[0].spots[1].construction==true` with an event what i expect is to render return statement inside second if statement.

Instead my render method crashes and i get this error:

```
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

This is timer function:

```
constructionCountDown = () =>{

        console.log("constructioncd")
        this.setState({constructionTime:this.state.constructionTime-1})



        if(this.state.constructionTime ==0){
          clearInterval(this.constructionCountDownInterval);
        }


      }
```

Answer (score 1):

These few lines look suspicious.

```
this.state.constructionTime = this.props.townData[0].spots[1].startTime - this.props.townData[0].spots[1].endTime;
```

You should always set states in componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate. You should also use `this.setState()` for this.

```
 this.constructionCountDownInterval= setInterval(this.constructionCountDown(),1000)
```

If you do this inside `render()`, it will be called on every render! Do verify it is your intended behavior. I suggest moving it to componentDidMount and remember to release it in componentWillUnmount, or risk resource leaks.

Comment: because i am checking it with  if(this.props.townData.length ==0 || this.constructionTimer == true){
          return;
        }      shouldnt it run just once ? then just return empty on other render calls ?  I am trying to start a timer

Comment: i guess i understand what you mean